# Converting from unknown format to date format in R

Tags: r, date, format

Somehow after importing data in R, it gives unknown format to dates such as

2016-12-01
2012-01-01

I tried to convert from unknown format to normal date format for hours now, but seems like it is impossible in R. Please help, how do I convert from unknown format to date format?

Comment: what do you mean by unkown format. If you do not know the order of month year day, this is impossible. for instance you cannot decide what 2012-11-11 means or worse yet 12-11-11 means as all numbers are valid for days months and years. If they are always in the same order and have the same separating character, you can use `as.Date`

Comment: I imported data from SAS it has dates in a normal format like 2012-12-01, 2012-01-01, 2012-10-02 etc.  but R can not recognize it, and instead of giving a date format gives unknown format for these dates. So how do i convert from unknown format to date format?

Comment: Still have no clue by what you mean by "unkown format". I feel like you are talking about a character vector, if that is the case, the answer below will solve it.

Comment: Data can have different types: char, numeric, boolean, integer etc. right? .R gives unknown type to my dates instead of data type, for whatever the reason. So how do i convert now from unknown type to data type?

Comment: You need to explain what exactly is happening. What is the code you've already written, what was the output? Does the answer below help in any way? Provide the data file if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a character vector:

```
d <- c("2016-12-01", "2012-01-01")
```

If this is the case you can do:

```
d2 <- as.Date(d, format = '%Y-%m-%d') 
# or format = '%Y-%d-%m' if that's the case
#> [1] "2016-12-01" "2012-01-01"
```

Or:

```
d3 <- as.POSIXct(d, format = '%Y-%m-%d') 
#> [1] "2016-12-01 CET" "2012-01-01 CET"
```

Or simply let the `anytime` package take the headache:

```
library(anytime)
d4 <- anytime(d, tz = 'CET')
#> [1] "2016-12-01 CET" "2012-01-01 CET"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you used the `rstudio` tag, I assume that you may have used the "Import Dataset" feature of RStudio. If that is the case, you can specify that a column contains dates when you are setting up the import. Just click on the column header near the small down arrow and you'll see a list of variable types, one of which is `Date`. If you choose that you'll be prompted for the date format string which, looking at your dates, is probably `%Y-%m-%d` (but that is something you need to check).

Comment: Yes that is what i did, but after i choose a date type and set a format %Y-%m-%d, it shows NA to all values, so i suppose it does not recognize my data. Then i decided to leave how it is with initial given data type "unknown" by default, and change it to date using code which i manage to do 3 weeks ago, but i didn't save the code that i used.

Comment: Most likely the column contains rows with something other than dates with that format string.

Comment: it contains blanks also. Ok so now i set char type which modifies my dates from 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-01T00:00:00. I suppose now i should be able to do something with it?